# Advanced Routing in Netlify React

Tags: reactjs, routes, netlify, react-routing

I had problems with the routing after deploying my react app on netlify. I inserted a _redirects file to my public folder with this code `/*    /index.html   200` as recommended.

Yet, when I refresh the page from an advanced route e.g. '/sceneries/beach', it always pushes me back to the index page. Locally it has been working perfectly before. Do you know how to solve this? My routes currently look like this:

in index.js

```
ReactDOM.render((
<Router history={history}>
    <App />
</Router>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

in App.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
          <Route path='/' component ={Home} />
          <Route path='/sceneries/:id' component ={Comparison} />
          <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
      </BrowserRouter>
```

Thanks a lot in advance! I really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you when I created a React app and deployed it on Netlify.
This is what worked for me, based on [this solution](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/issues/457):

1. Create a file named `netlify.toml` in the root/main folder of your project.
2. Inside of this file, add this code:

`[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200`

3. Save and deploy your website with git add commit push.
4. Wait for your site to re-deploy on Netlify.
5. Test your website with refresh.

Let me know if you have any additional questions, I'm happy to help :)